# Programmatically bookmark pages in bookmark toolbar using firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, bookmarks

I'm trying to make a firefox extension that bookmarks the current page and adds an entry in the bookmarks toolbar. Using the example in the documentation found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks) I was only able to only bookmark a link but not make it appear in the bookmarks toolbar. I was unable to find anything helpful in the documentation or on google related to this.

Here's my code:

```
let { Bookmark, save } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");

// Create a new bookmark instance, unsaved
let bookmark = Bookmark({ title: "Test", url: "http://mozilla.org" });

// Attempt to save the bookmark instance to the Bookmarks database
// and store the emitter
let emitter = save(bookmark);
```

Is this simply not possible or is there something in the documentation that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `group` to `TOOLBAR`, like so:

```
let { Bookmark, TOOLBAR, save } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");

// Create a new bookmark instance, unsaved
let bookmark = Bookmark({
    title: "Test",
    url: "http://mozilla.org",
    group: TOOLBAR,
});

// Attempt to save the bookmark instance to the Bookmarks database
// and store the emitter
let emitter = save(bookmark);
```

There is more information on [this part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#TOOLBAR) of the page on MDN

Comment: Apparently it's TOOLBAR without apostrophes and you have to initialize it with the require statement. I posted an answer to make it clearer. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is how it's done:

```
let { Bookmark, TOOLBAR, save } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");

// Create a new bookmark instance, unsaved
let bookmark = Bookmark({
    title: "Test",
    url: "http://mozilla.org",
    group: TOOLBAR
});

// Attempt to save the bookmark instance to the Bookmarks database
// and store the emitter
let emitter = save(bookmark);
```