# Identify the bookmarks toolbar folder (Firefox Webextension)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, html5-apps

I read the MDN documentation about how to get a reference to the bookmarks tree und to navigate within. But how do I know which folder represents the bookmarks toolbar? This toolbar is named differently depending on the locale. I am not sure whether a user is still allowed to select an arbitrary folder for this, but this was possible some years ago.

I found this post: [Programmatically bookmark pages in bookmark toolbar using firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112538/programmatically-bookmark-pages-in-bookmark-toolbar-using-firefox-extension)

but this is not about the new webextension API that everybody has to use now.

Comment: You can use this

browser.bookmarks.get("toolbar_____").then((value) => {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
}, null);

Comment: Please note that the bookmark ID "toolbar_____" is not guaranteed to be stable, but you can probably keep using this for now.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, there are special IDs you can search for.

```js
// If you just need the node or its contents
let toolbar_node = await browser.bookmarks.get("toolbar_____");
let toolbar_subtree = await browser.bookmarks.getSubTree("toolbar_____");

// If you're walking the tree on your own
if (node.id == "toolbar_____") { /* it's the toolbar */ }
```

They were apparently introduced in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1071505 4 years ago, to be generally used by other Firefox subsystems as hardcoded values. While that can change, it's unlikely and would have be for a good reason because of all pre-existing dependencies elsewhere.

That said, their use in WebExtensions is not documented.